# Electron Updater - Digital Ocean Spaces

Tags: javascript, electron, digital-ocean

```
export default class AppUpdater {
    constructor() {
        const options = {
            provider: 'generic',
            url: 'https://example.com/auto-updates'
        }

        const autoUpdater = new NsisUpdater(options)
        autoUpdater.addAuthHeader(`Bearer ${token}`)
        autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify()
    }
}
```

I am trying to make an updater for my electron app and I want to use Digital Ocean Spaces. Can anybody help me to format the above code to Digital Ocean Spaces format. In Electron Updater docs there is not a specific guide for how to connect Digital Ocean.

Comment: Is the NsisUpdater required or just from an example?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/natearmagost/electron-updater-digitalocean-example):
In the `"build"` section in package.json you need

```json
"publish": {
    "provider": "spaces",
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "region": "nyc3",
    "acl": "public-read"
}
```

Put your DO_KEY_ID and DO_SECRET_KEY in electron-builder.env which you exclude via neagtive selector, again in the `"build"`section:

```
"files": [
    "!electron-builder.env"
]
```